# Error in py2exe python app using Chaco in pyside

Tags: python, pyside, py2exe, enthought, chaco

`enter code here`I've a program that uses Enthought's Chaco plots embedded in a pyside (Qt4) GUI. It also uses numpy, but nevermind that. The program runs fine on multiple platforms directly from Python but when I create a .exe for win32 with py2exe I get an error when the .exe is run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "awesome_program.pyw", line 19, in <module>
  File "plotwidget.pyc", line 13, in <module>
  File "enable\api.pyc", line 8, in <module>
  File "enable\base.pyc", line 35, in <module>
  File "enable\colors.pyc", line 246, in <module>
  File "traitsui\qt4\color_editor.pyc", line 21, in <module>
  File "traitsui\editors\__init__.pyc", line 22, in <module>
  File "traitsui\editors\api.pyc", line 29, in <module>
  File "traitsui\editors\list_str_editor.pyc", line 33, in <module>
  File "pyface\image_resource.pyc", line 18, in <module>
  File "pyface\toolkit.pyc", line 73, in <module>
  File "pyface\toolkit.pyc", line 38, in _init_toolkit
  File "pyface\toolkit.pyc", line 31, in import_toolkit
ImportError: No module named init
```

The setup.py file is:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# setup_win32.py

# Create an .exe for win32 systems.
# Run this with:
#   python setup_win32.py py2exe

import sys
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
# from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includes = []
includes.append("PySide.QtUiTools")
includes.append("PySide.QtXml")

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(options = {"py2exe": {"dll_excludes":["MSVCP90.dll"],
                            "includes": includes}},
      name='awesomeprogram',
      version='0.01',
      description='A program to visualize stuff.',
      author='John Doe',
      author_email='dude@email.com',
      console=[{"script": "awesome_program.pyw"}])
```

I'm fairly new to Chaco and py2exe, but I get the feeling that something needs to be explicitly included from Enthought's suite in my py2exe setup file? Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used py2exe, but I have some experience with py2app (which I think is similar). It fails to include many of the Enthought/chaco packages, so you need to include them manually in setup.py. Here's what I did:

```
OPTIONS = dict(
           includes = [
                       # The backends are dynamically imported and thus we need to
                       # tell py2app about them.
                       'kiva.*',
                       'enable.*',
                       'enable.qt4.*',
                       'pyface.*',
                       'pyface.ui.qt4.*',
                       'pyface.ui.qt4.action.*',
                       'pyface.ui.qt4.timer.*',
                       'pyface.ui.qt4.wizard.*',
                       'pyface.ui.qt4.workbench.*',
                       'traitsui.qt4.*',
                       'traitsui.qt4.extra.*',
                       'PyQt4.pyqtconfig',
                       'glob.*'],
           argv_emulation = True)

setup(
      app=APP,
      options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
      setup_requires=['py2app'],
      )
```

If you replace use a similar OPTIONS (of course replacing `py2app` with `py2exe`, and probably `PyQt4` with `PySide`), it may work for you. If it fails with another import, just add it to the include list.

Comment: Now a new error about Qt4 images, but from Enthought:

Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "awesome_program.pyw", line 19, in <module>
      File "plotwidget.pyc", line 13, in <module>
      File "enable\api.pyc", line 21, in <module>
      File "enable\markers.pyc", line 18, in <module>
      File "enable\compiled_path.pyc", line 17, in <module>
      File "enable\toolkit.pyc", line 47, in <module>
      File "enable\toolkit.pyc", line 40, in _init_toolkit
    ImportError: Unable to import the image backend for the qt4 toolkit (reason: ['I
mportError: No module named qt4.image\n']).

Comment: You need to track down the root import and include it in the above list. Modules that are dynamically loaded are missed by py2exe and must be added manually.

Comment: Any idea how this would translate to cx_freeze?

Comment: @AdamHughes sorry, never used cx_freeze.

Comment: py2app IIUC only makes Mac OSX binaries.  I really am trying to go platform-independent.  `cx_freeze` guys have got me pretty far through the process so far, so I think it will be possible.  I will try py2app in the meantime, thanks.